# Visual studio: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or server is not responding

Tags: sql, excel, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I know there are duplicates thread for this issue but so far the solution in those threads are not working for me so I decided to put a new thread.

I am trying to generate a "report" function where it will export the report to excel when I click the export button. This is my code:

```
 ` case "RPTDAILYISSUEVOU":
                 db.Open();
                  command = new SqlCommand("M_RPT_DailyIssuedVoucher", db);
                strControlValue = GetControlValue(pnlRecordRange, "useDateTimeFrom", ControlType.LabelDateTimePickerFrom);
                if (strControlValue != null)
                {
                    dtFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(strControlValue);
                }
                strControlValue = GetControlValue(pnlRecordRange, "useDateTimeTo", ControlType.LabelDateTimePickerTo);
                if (strControlValue != null)
                {
                    dtTo = Convert.ToDateTime(strControlValue);

                }



                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventCode",strEvCode);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocID", strLocID);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", strStatusDIV);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IssuedBy", strIssuedBy);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DtFrom", dtFrom);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DtTo", dtTo);



                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                ExportExcel(dr);
                db.Close();
              //  rpt.View_DailyIssuedVouReport(paramFields, strEvCode, strLocID, strStatusDIV, strIssuedBy, dtFrom, dtTo);
                break;`
```

There doesn't seem to be any problem when i run the system but when i clicked "Export" in my system where it's supposed to generate an excel file/document, it gives an error " timeoutexpired. timeout period elapsed prior to completion of operation or server is not responding "

Any idea how to fix this? What is the underlying problem?

Comment: did this exception thrown in this line `dr = command.ExecuteReader();`?

Comment: no, just the error message i get  was as mentioned in the tittle